# Child nodes inside SKNode disappears with fast shaking device with CMMotionManager applied to move balls

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've create a SKNode with physicsBody edgeFromLoop circular inside which i've added 8 small circular nodes. and 8 circular nodes are moving with CMMotionManager inside Parent circular node. with fast motion shake some balls disappears from screen. SKScene Class given below

Balls only disappears when anyone shake mobile hard randomly.

There are 8 balls initially but after some hard shake reduced.

[image]

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
  let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

  var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 108)
  var sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(getRandomSound(), waitForCompletion: false)
  var collisionBitmasks: [UInt32] = [UInt32]()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    Circle.fillTexture = SKTexture.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "img_Ball") ?? UIImage())
    Circle.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
    Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
    Circle.lineWidth = 0.0
    Circle.fillColor = SKColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFrom: UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: Circle.frame.minX + 12,
                                                                                                y: Circle.frame.minY + 12,
                                                                                                width: Circle.frame.width - 24,
                                                                                                height: Circle.frame.height - 24)).cgPath)
    Circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    Circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Circle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    addChild(Circle)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    startAcceleroMeter()
    for index in 1...8 {
      addBalls(index)
    }
  }

  func stop() {
    motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    Circle.children.forEach { (ball) in
      ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
      ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }
  }

  func startAcceleroMeter() {
    Circle.children.forEach { (ball) in
      ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
      ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    }
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: .main) { (motionData, error) in
      let gravity = CGVector.init(dx: (motionData?.acceleration.x ?? 0.0) * 20, dy: (motionData?.acceleration.y ?? 0.0) * 20)
      print(gravity)
      self.physicsWorld.gravity = gravity

    }
  }

  func stopPlaying() -> [String] {
    var dictionary = [String]()

    for (_, ball) in (Circle.children).enumerated() {
      dictionary.append("\(ball.position.x), \(ball.position.y), 0.0")
    }
    return dictionary
  }

  func addBalls(_ ballNo: Int) {
    let ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: 12)
    ball.name = "ball\(ballNo)"
    ball.fillTexture = SKTexture.init(linearGradientWithAngle: CGFloat.pi, colors: [BallColors(rawValue: ballNo)?.toUIColor(false) ?? UIColor(), BallColors(rawValue: ballNo)?.toUIColor(true) ?? UIColor()], locations: [0, 1], size: ball.frame.size)
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.white
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: 12)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.1
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.1
    ball.physicsBody?.mass = 0.349065870046616
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: Circle.frame.midX - CGFloat(ballNo), y: Circle.frame.midY - CGFloat(ballNo))
    ball.physicsBody?.fieldBitMask = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32.init(ballNo + 100)
    let collisionBitMask = UInt32.init(ballNo + 20) | UInt32.init(ballNo + 100)
    collisionBitmasks.append(collisionBitMask)
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =  collisionBitMask //To be different for each
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32.init(ballNo + 20)
    Circle.addChild(ball)
  }

  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
  }

}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if collisionBitmasks.contains(contact.bodyA.collisionBitMask) && collisionBitmasks.contains(contact.bodyB.collisionBitMask) {
      run(sound)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I only have guesses at this moment, but I would do the following.
1. Set `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` for the circle
2. Don't change `isDynamic`.

Comment: Also is the circle suppose to move or can it be static (set `isDynamic` to false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a hidden magic here.  Each small ball adds a constraint that can prevent any accident from high speeds:

```
   ball.constraints = [SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(upperLimit: 108 - 12), to: Circle)]
```